# Reliability of algorithm performance testing based on unit framework

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, unit-testing, time

For my PhD I am writing a DEM (Discrete Element Method) simulation in c++ describing particle flow which is computational intensive. I have a lot of different algorithms in place for the calculation of different parameters. The run time per algorithm can vary significantly based on the configuration of points (where the number of points stay the same). For testing, a good amount of unit tests are in place with different configurations and number of points.

For optimization and performance testing it seems easiest to run the specific unit tests multiple times, under the assumption that the time required by the unit testing framework is constant I can compare different algorithm performances against each other. So in pseudo code I want to do this, where algorithm1 and algorithm2 are different implementations of a single algorithm and the different unitTests are different input configurations:

```
//Preformance test algorithm1
timer = 0;
startTimer();
for(n = 1000) {
     unitTest1(algorithm1);
     unitTest2(algorithm1);
     .....
 }
 print(timer);

//Performance test algorithm2
timer = 0;
startTimer();
for(n = 1000) {
     unitTest1(algorithm2);
     unitTest2(algorithm2);
     .....
 }
 print(timer);
```

**Question:** Is this a valid way to do performance testing that will yield reliable and comparable results or can the unit testing framework invalidate my results in some way? Also can this method be extended to test performance when the code is written for parallel processing.

Additional information: The unit framework I am using is the Boost Test Library and due to long run times I cannot efficiently performance test the code as a whole with different configurations.

Comment: If I recall correctly, people working on compilers mentioned that single operations are "unobservable", meaning that it won't be possible to actually measure it exactly when it ends. Though if the difference is big enough, it will be negligible. Probably looking at assembly will be good to check if the compiler did move some statements around.

Comment: @Incomputable: A unit test is likely not a single operation (assuming you are referring to a single CPU instruction). So while correct for some architectures, it doesn't apply here.

Comment: @IInspectable, that's why I mentioned if the difference is big enough part. The difference between small datasets might not be that stable, this is what I meant.

Comment: @Incomputable: The unit test and algorithms are not single operations, I thought about looking at the assembly code, but the algorithms are to big for me to make sense of the assembly code.

Comment: @D.J.Klomp I probably exaggerated a problem. Just watch out for weird things. Static analysis of compilers do wonders these days. Also you might want to consider google benchmark library. C time() uses cpu time, whereas C++ chrono uses more or less real time. It might be worth considering which one is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, Boost is not needed for this task; there are numerous ways to do that with standard C++, I have some ways in [Time measurements](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/1651-2/), where `std::crhono` seems to do the trick.

A DEM requires a number of points as input, so I would run my algorithm on different inputs, and then take the *average* execution time.

I would the same thing for the other algorithm, but in a different program, since you do not know what the OS is doing under the hood. Moreover you want both algorithms to do a cold start regarding caching, and executing both algorithms in the same program may give a slight advantage for the second algorithm, in certain cases.

So I would do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>

#define UTN 10 // Unit tests number

int main ()
{
  // populate `unitTest` vector
  ...
  using namespace std::chrono;

  high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  for(int i = 0; i < UTN; ++i
      unitTest[i](algorithm1);

  high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);

  std::cout << "It took me " << time_span.count()/UTN << " seconds.";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Now I wrote down the reported time and then executed the above program again, but now with `algorithm2()` in place, measure the average time it took and compare.